# How should I go about writing a naive Bayesian classifier in Python?

Tags: python, classification

I need to create a weather prediction system in Python.  What it will do is take in a file which contains weather data — such as temperature (mean, max, min), wind, dew point, humidity, condition (fog, rain, snow, none) etc. — and use this to train a naive Bayesian model so it can then predict the condition of the next day, i.e will the next day be fog, rain, snow or none.

This is part of an assignment so they provided code which handles the input of the data file, I just need to create the classifier but I am not sure how to do it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

The `nltk.classify.naivebayes` module may be what you're looking for.  Here is a page with examples of [how to use nltk classifiers](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch06.html). It shows how to classify text, but should provide some hints as to how to train a classifier based on your weather features.

Comment: I think Sam has to write a naive Bayesian classifier though? Rather than use a pre-existing one?

Comment: Ahh yes, good point -- I assumed by the phrase "create a classifier" he just needed to do the training part, not build a naive Bayes implementation from scratch.

Comment: As of today, the link in the answer requires authorization.

Answer (score 2):

Paul Graham described Bayesian classification, in the context of spam filtering, here:

- http://www.paulgraham.com/spam.html

Might be a good starting point.

Comment: You beat me to it, +1. A great intro to bayesian stats.

Comment: @Richard: the follow-up’s really good too, but it’s mainly spam-focused optimisations if I remember correctly.

Comment: That was a good article but I am still quite confused on how to start.  Do I need to generate probabilities for my data e.g getting probabilities for temperatures?

Comment: @sam: no idea I’m afraid, I’ve never written one. (Bit beyond my limited skills.)

Comment: @sam: oh — if you can get your hands on it, the book [‘Programming Collective Intelligence’ by Toby Segaran](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529321) has a more practical discussion of how to code a Bayesian classifier, and, I believe, sampel code. But don’t forget — writing code badly is the best way to learn how to write good code, which is why you’ve been set this exercise. (I never took a course, so I’ve written my bad practise code on the job, which doesn’t help anyone.)